# showing elements of array in single edit box control

Tags: c++, arrays, controls, edit

I have created dialog based MFC and I want to show the array elements that come from serial COM PORT. it should be implemented using Edit box control. I want to show the received characters sequentially with one space between them.

Comment: So, how can we help you sir?

Comment: assume that we have typical array with size of 20. please tell me how I can show it in Edit  box control.